# Rails Application deployed on Heroku writing to localhost db and redirecting to localhost view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment

I recently deployed a RoR app to Heroku.
The app loads fine.
I have a 'new' action that creates a new model record via a form submission (POST).
The issue is:
On submit, the controller writes to my local database and redirects to my local view corresponding to the controller action: http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/myview

My production database is empty! Any ideas on what is causing this and the fix?? Why is my remote deployment on Heroku accessing localhost???

I only need production on Heroku.

advTHANXance!

Comment: This is Rails 5 btw :)

Comment: Share your code here whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails db:create
RAILS_ENV=production rails db:migrate
```

But if you don't run those two, you will surely get migrate error.

Please provide some details about your error.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Check if you have a postgres plugin in heroku console

2) Secondly when you push check if you get any error related to PG .

3) dont forget to do heroku restart --app appname

4) login to heroku using **heroku bash** and then run rails c, then check that what database you are using 

for it use the command
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
```

now you will get response like

```
{:adapter=>ADAPTER_NAME, :host=>HOST, :port=>PORT, 
    :database=>DB, :pool=>POOL, :username=>USERNAME, 
    :password=>PASSWORD}
```

if you see dbname as the name in heroku dashboard database name 
if it is same then the database is what you are using is of production.
and for transfer to local,re-check your routes and clear your cache,thats the only reason for it.